# How to join two objects with different color

Tags: modeling

I'm all new to Blender. I've managed to import my logo and it has an X of two colors.

How can I join these two objects so that it becomes one object with the red part being "on top" when I extrude it to 3D?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multiple possibilities:

OR: Import your (I guess svg) X object as 3 objects instead of 2. In Illustrator, you can use the "Pathfinder" panel to slice 2 objects in 3 objects.

OR: Dirty fix: bring the red part slightly closer to the camera.

After one of these fixes, you can join both objects (ctrl j) in Blender and extrude them as 1 object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could better create a mesh with two materials, and different mesh part assigned to each of them, which you could later extrude as expected, if I got what you mean, like:

[image]

To do this, your mesh must be subdivided in different faces, and when you have more than one material on the object, you can select each and "assign" it to selected faces, like:

[image]

Comment: This looks to be answering my question - very good image example (even though I want the red part to be the dominant in the middle - that is my goal). What I have now is that the these two objects are curves. How do I take it from there?

Comment: Just invert the color assignment to have red "on top" - You can convert curves to meshes (ALT-C) but since in the end you need to have one single mesh, athough with different materials on different faces, it could be better to start from a single curve, then import it in blender, convert it to a 2D mesh, assign materials, and then extruding to 3D. let me know if you need some example.